# Decorators: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, compiler-errors, decorator

I ran the following Python code except for the last line: 'display()':

```
def decorator_function(original_function):
   def wrapper_function():
      print('message')
      return original_function()
   return wrapper_function()

@decorator_function
def display():
   print('Display function ran')

display()
```

Surprisingly, it displayed the right messages as if I would have run the command 'display()', but when I tried to run this command also, the following error showed: 'line 11, in 
display()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

What could be causing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the brackets in the return:

```
def decorator_function(original_function):
    def wrapper_function():
        print('message')
        return original_function
    return wrapper_function

@decorator_function
def display():
    print('Display function ran')

display()
```